# is my interpertation for $sometext =~ s/([^$sgn])j$/$1X/g; in perl correct

Tags: regex, perl

I would appreciate if you could please correct my understanding of the following code in perl:

```
my $sgn            = "(b|f|h|m)";  
$sometext =~ s/([^$sgn])d$/$1X/g;
```

What I think is happening here is that it tries to match a character which is not in the $sgn.  then if this character happens to be the one next to the last letter and if the last character  is d it replaces the two last character by X?  For example **book** will not change but **bad** will change to **bX**.
Put it simply if the last two letters are a combination any of the letters not in **$sgn** and **d** it will replace them by X.
Thanks in advance for your comments.
Bid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: You can test your regex [at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pxBw5l/1) (explanation on the right side). Be aware that `[`...`]` describes a charcter-set. It does not make much sense to put `(b|f|h|m)` into a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) - `[^(b|f|h|m)]` is equivalent to `[^bfhm)(|]`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I did try it there.  I just wanted to verify if my understanding is correct and I need to convert it Dart, so before that I have to make sure  the logic of the code is what explained

Comment: That is most likely an error, is what @bobblebubble explains.  Assuming that they mean either-of those four (by `|`s in `$sgn`), then you have `s/([^bfhm]d$/$1X/` (that `/g` modifier makes no sense since the pattern is anchored to the end of string so I removed it).  Then the logic is: if  a character which is neither of those four precedes a `d` and which is the last char in the string, then keep that character but replace `d` by `X`.  So `bad` becomes `baX`. (It keeps that character because it captures it with `()` and puts it back with that `$1` in replacement.)

Comment: Note that `$` does not mean the same thing in JS/Dart regex patterns and Perl regex patterns.

Answer (score 1):

It replaces the last or second last character of `$sometext` depending on the last preceding and following character.

- If the last character is `d`, replace the `d` with an `X` if the preceding character isn't one of `b`, `f`, `h`, `m`, `|`, `(`, or `)`.

  ```
  ...ad       ⇒       ...aX
  ...cd       ⇒       ...cX
  ...!d       ⇒       ...!X

  ...bd       ⇒       ...bd
  ...fd       ⇒       ...fd
  ...(d       ⇒       ...(d
  ...|d       ⇒       ...|d
  ...)d       ⇒       ...)d
  ```
- If the last two characters are `d␊`, replace the `d` with an `X` if the preceding character isn't one of `b`, `f`, `h`, `m`, `|`, `(`, or `)`.

  ```
  ...ad␊      ⇒       ...aX␊
  ...cd␊      ⇒       ...cX␊
  ...!d␊      ⇒       ...!X␊

  ...bd␊      ⇒       ...bd␊
  ...fd␊      ⇒       ...fd␊
  ...(d␊      ⇒       ...(d␊
  ...|d␊      ⇒       ...|d␊
  ...)d␊      ⇒       ...)d␊
  ```
- No change if the string ends with anything else.

  ```
  ...ae       ⇒       ...ae
  ...ce       ⇒       ...ce

  ...ae␊      ⇒       ...ae␊
  ...ce␊      ⇒       ...ce␊
  ```

---

Note that the author obviously meant to use

```perl
my $sgn = "(b|f|h|m)";
```

instead of

```perl
my $sgn = "bfhm";
```

Note that the author might have meant to use

```
d\z
```

instead of

```perl
d$
```

Comment: Thanks for your detained explanation, I do appreciate it.